# Java code to display number of years till next leap year

Tags: java

I wrote  code to check whether the year entered is a leap year
or not. But now I am trying to add on so that If it is not, then my program must display the number of years until the next leap year. This is  how I did The code for the first bit of my program

[image]

Comment: Please copy / paste code instead of screenshots. What is your question?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], [make an attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to solve the problem yourself), and then *ask a question, if you still have one*. Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: To display how much years you need until to the next leap year, just create a loop which increase your year by 1, until reach leap year, and count all this `+1`.

Comment: Does it compile? Does your IDE (IntellJ) or Java show any (syntax-) errors? Post them, so we can help you to solve. Is the last closing curly-bracket `}` missing?

Comment: The question seems not new ️ What was your __research__? E.g. here [`[java] leap year`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+leap+year) you'll find answers - with __code as text__ to copy and reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Turn this into a function that returns true/false based on a parameter. Then do the initial check, and after that a simple for loop from year to year + 4, and call the function with these new values.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int year = 2021;
    System.out.println(IsLeapYear(year));
    
    for (int i = year; i < year + 4; i++) {
        if (IsLeapYear(i)) {
            System.out.println("The next leap year is " + i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean IsLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
}
```

Output:
`false` 
`The next leap year is 2024*/`

As per @mcemperor's request, here is a version with a while loop, which works correctly:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int year = 2020;
    int i = year;
    System.out.println(IsLeapYear(year));
    while (!IsLeapYear(++i));
    System.out.println("The next leap year is " + i);
}

public static boolean IsLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
}
```

Comment: Well, `year + 4` is not sufficient. If you set `year` to `1897`, nothing is displayed. I would personally rewrite the for loop to a while loop: `int nextLeapYear = year + 1; while (!isLeapYear(nextLeapYear)) { nextLeapYear++; } System.out.println("The next leap year is " + nextLeapYear);`.

Comment: You are right. I ignored the part of the algorithm where certain seemingly leap years are not really leap years. A while loop can work, it might be better actually, or adding tops 10 years to the given year might work as well (year + 10). Because it breaks out of the loop once you find a leap year, it will have the same result.

Comment: Tip: [`Year.isLeap( long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#isLeap(long))

Comment: I assumed OP was working on some kind of assignment/homework so I went with his own original algorithm. I personally wasn't aware of `Year.isLeap(_long)`, so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the closest leap yea by using an iterator (generator) to compute each successive leap year:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class LeapYearDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(closestLeapYear(LocalDateTime.now()));
    }
    
    public static int closestLeapYear(LocalDateTime date) {
        return LeapYearIterator.isLeapYear(date.getYear())
            ? date.getYear()
            : new LeapYearIterator(date.getYear()).next();
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LeapYearIterator implements Iterator<Integer>, Iterable<Integer> {
    private static final GregorianCalendar CALENDAR;
    private int year;
    
    static {
        CALENDAR = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    }
        
    public LeapYearIterator(int yearStart) {
        this.year = yearStart;
    }
        
    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        do this.year++;
        while (!isLeapYear(this.year));
        return this.year;
    }
        
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { return true; }
        
    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() { return this; }
    
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return CALENDAR.isLeapYear(year);
    }
}
```

I based this on some JavaScript code I wrote below.

```js
const isLeapYear = (year) =>
  year % 400 === 0 || (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0);

function* nextLeap(date) {
  let year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
  while (true) {
    if (isLeapYear(year++)) {
      yield (year - 1);
    }
  };
};

const closestLeapYear = (date) =>
  isLeapYear(date.getFullYear())
    ? date.getFullYear()
    : nextLeap(date).next().value;

console.log(closestLeapYear(new Date()));
```

Comment: The skipping `while` loop is simple and powerful. `Iterator` as generator a proven pattern. What about reusing Java's [`GregorianCalendar.isLeapYear(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isLeapYear(int)) to test?

Comment: @hc_dev I updated my response to include the use of that method; but since the method is non-static, I have to create an internal `GregorianCalendar` instance.